# Laravel local virtual host returning FatalErrorException on MAMP server

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a project, I decided to create local virtual host to keep my URL clean and easy.

When ever I hit a route that uses a controller it returns this error:
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Can't use function return value in write context

I cannot figure what is causing this.

Anyone else run into this type of error on this environment? Any tips are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the code for your controller?

Answer (score 1):

There are two general causes for this error.  The first is something like this:

```
echo $_POST('test');
```

Notice that instead of indexing the array, you're calling a function.  This will cause this error.  Another cause of that particular error could be something like this:

```
$test = ' ';
if(empty(trim($test)) { // There be dragons
```

This is because the only valid arguments to the empty function are variables (you cannot call a function inside the call to `empty`). Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Note: Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else
>   will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not
>   work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

The same restrictions on `empty` also apply to `isset` [as well](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the problem. I found a solution. I bought a new SSD hard drive and installed Ubunu Linux on a partition for all my web dev needs. Now I don't have to deal with any of the Apple related web dev pains.